# Parse large image from SOAP/XML in android

Tags: android, xml, image, wcf, soap

Hi I am working on an android app which relies on being able to fetch images among other data from our server, i.e., the image is contained in a tag as part of the response. The communication with the server is based on WCF and SOAP.

Up until the point where we need to fetch images it has worked fine. But when we need to fetch an image from the server the app takes a substantial amount of time and consumes a lot of memory when parsing the response from the server containing the image. The images we are working with are typically of the size of 1500 x 1000 pixels. The image itself is transmitted as a base64 encoded byte array.

Currently we are parsing the response using a DOM xml parser, which I know to be prone to huge memory consumption but insofar has not given any problems(aside from parsing images). Furthermore some minor tests using XMLPull, which seems to be the recommended XML parser on the android platform, has resolved in pretty much the same issue, huge memory and time consumption.

I suspect that the issue stems from the image being converted to a string or byte array both of which should consume quite a bit of memory considering the size of the image.

Bellow is an example of the code we currently are using to parse the response:

```
public static Document parseResponse(InputStream response)
{
    Document parsedResponse = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {

        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        parsedResponse = builder.parse(response);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return parsedResponse;
}
```

And the response is fetched using an Async-Task using the following code:

```
protected Document doInBackground(ServerRequest... requests) {

        ServerRequest request = requests[0];
    HttpPost postRequest = request.postMethod;

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(postRequest);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Document parsedResponse = null;
    try {
        InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        parsedResponse = ServerRequest.parseResponse(stream);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return parsedResponse;
}
```

Currently it is not possible to fetch the image itself using a URL, i.e., it comes as part of the XML from the server, otherwise something like [Android Hive - Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) would probably be the way to go.

Before delving into something like kSOAP2 I would like to find out if there was a simple fix to the above approach or if I've missed something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched lot of on internet for your alternate solution. But it seems that memory constraints is always in middle of the way for phone.

Really 1500 * 1000 px image is too huge for android mobile to eat. I was also faced the same problem in one of my projects.

Only way is you can parse that string on server side, store it temporarily and pass the image path in response. This is the best approach i am feeling right now. I am still searching for solution. If found, i will let you know.

Your above approach will slow down the mobile and also kill the useful apps services running in background. :(

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, parsing the string server side, at least I think, is not feasible since the parsed string would then be transmitted again as XML which then should be read and stored in memory. I think the link/URL approach from Android Hive is the most simple solution. Regarding the image size I agree.